# Payment to integrate iAd in your app?

Tags: ios, iad

I'd like to integrate iAd in my application to show advertisement. How can I create and submit an iAd campaign? Is there any payment for it?

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_iad_integration.htm

Comment: is there any charges to integrate iAd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum budget for an iAd Workbench campaign is **$50**. iAd Workbench offers two payment options: credit card (Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover) or line of credit. Please note that price is drastically lower than the required buy-in when the iAd program first debuted in 2010.

To create and submit an iAd campaign, sign in to iAd Workbench using your Apple ID and follow these steps:

1. Set up your campaign by selecting the app or product you want to promote, choosing a bid type, and giving your campaign a name.
2. Set your target audience, country, flight dates (the dates you want the campaign to run), budget, and bids.
3. Create your ad by assigning it a banner (the part of your ad users tap) and a destination (where users are taken when they tap the banner).
4. Review your campaign and submit it to iAd for approval.

Reference: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202923